# Как получить value элемента?

Tags: jquery, input, javascript

Здравствуйте. У меня на сайте есть много динамически созданных элементов `<input>`.

Мне понадобилось добавлять значения с них в базу данных запросом ajax. Возник вопрос о том, как мне сделать элементы уникальными, чтобы доставать именно то поле, которое нужно. Поэтому я имени (атрибуту `name`) элементов присвоил имя `j` итерации цикла и по клику на кнопке передаю этот номер, и номер передаётся.

Но как теперь получить `value` этого элемента? При клике я передаю значение так: `onclick='call($j)'`.

Если сделать так (допустим, `j=7`): `alert($('input[name='7']').val())`, то выведет value элемента с именем `j=7`.

Но так:

```
function call(variable) {
    alert($('input[name='variable']').val())
}
```

и так:

```
function call(variable) {
    alert($('input[name=variable]').val())
}
```

будет сообщение `undefined`. Как я понял, функция не понимает, что нужно именно переменную передать, а не просто имя `variable` присвоить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как тут получить `value`?

Comment: В селекторы переменные нужно передавать не в кавычках, в вашем случае это будет вот так:

$('input[name=' + variable + ']').val()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как написал уже [@MasterAlex](/users/22273/masteralex), нужно составить текстовую строку вида:

```
input[name='value']
```

Не забываем про внутренние кавычки:

```
$("input[name='" +name+ "']").val()
```

И лучше не писать назначение событий в тегах (`onclick..`), а назначить слушателя событий – [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/17bL9ns2/).

Answer (score 0):

вот вам на чистом js

```js
var element = document.getElementById("myElement");
console.log(element.value);
```

```html
<input id="myElement" type="text" value="значение" />
```